# What is an 'elastic' metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> If $(X,\tau)$ has a metric topology (Let $d$ denote the metric), we can consider $Top^h(X,X)$ to be a topological space itself (**$Top^h(X,X)$ is the set of homeomorphisms from $X$ to itself**). Explicitly, we can define an 'elastic' metric on $Top^h(X,X)$ by $d'(f,g)=sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),g(x))$ and use the corresponding metric topology.

What is the meaning of 'elastic' in the above text? Also, why is the metric above defined? How can you guarantee existence of $sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),g(x))$? I don't think compactness of $X$ is required because $X=\mathbb{R}$ is used as an example of this topological space later on in the notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the supremum defining $d'$ can be infinite when $X$ isn't compact.  For example, when $X=\mathbb R$, consider $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$.  But a "metric" that sometimes takes the value $\infty$ can still serve to define a topology, and that's presumably what the author intended.

As for "elastic", that's probably intended to just suggest an intuition, related to the idea that topology lets you deform objects by stretching or compressing them. In particular, if $g$ is the identity map and $f$ is an arbitrary homeomorphism $X\to X$, then $d'(f,g)$ measures how severely $f$ stretches $X$, i.e., how far it moves points in $X$ from their original position.

Comment: P.S. I don't think the "elastic" analogy is very good. Using $\mathbb R$ and $g(x)=x$ as an example again, but modifying $f$ to make $f(x)=(1+\varepsilon)x$ with very small positive $\varepsilon$, we still get $d'(f,g)=\infty$ but $f$ stretches distances  only very slightly, by a factor $1+\varepsilon$.